# ProcessLoop управление процессами

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Идея проста: есть некоторый набор процессов, которые последовательно выполняются шаг за шагом. Процесс можно поставить на паузу или завершить. Класс ProcessLoop как раз занимается последовательным выполнением процессов и завершается, когда все процессы, который он содержит, завершились.

Вот код ([ideone.com](http://ideone.com/zci9Bf)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Process {
public:
    virtual bool isPause() = 0;
    virtual bool isDone() = 0;
    virtual void tick() = 0;
};

class ProcessLoop {
public:
    void addProcess(Process &p) {
        processes.push_back(p);
    }
    void run() {
        bool done;
        do {
            done = true;
            for (Process &p : processes) {
                if (!p.isDone()) {
                    done = false;
                    if (!p.isPause()) p.tick();
                }
            }
        } while (!done);
    }
private:
    vector<Process> processes;
};

class ProcessA : public Process {
public:
    bool isPause() { return false; }
    bool isDone() { return counter >= 5; }
    void tick() {
        cout << "counter == " << counter++ << endl;
    }
private:
    int counter = 0;
};

int main() {
    ProcessLoop ploop;
    ProcessA processa;
    ploop.addProcess(processa);
    ploop.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка больше кода:

```
In file included from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = Process; _Args = {const Process&}; _Tp = Process]':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:256:4:   required from 'static std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Process; _Args = {const Process&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<Process>; std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> = void]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:402:16:   required from 'static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Process; _Args = {const Process&}; _Alloc = std::allocator<Process>; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:917:30:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Process; _Alloc = std::allocator<Process>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Process]'
prog.cpp:15:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Process'
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
prog.cpp:5:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Process':
 class Process {
       ^
prog.cpp:7:15: note:    virtual bool Process::isPause()
  virtual bool isPause() = 0;
               ^
prog.cpp:8:15: note:    virtual bool Process::isDone()
  virtual bool isDone() = 0;
               ^
prog.cpp:9:15: note:    virtual void Process::tick()
  virtual void tick() = 0;
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:62:0,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = Process; _Args = {Process}]':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Process*>; _ForwardIterator = Process*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:126:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Process*>; _ForwardIterator = Process*]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Process*>; _ForwardIterator = Process*; _Tp = Process]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:303:2:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = Process*; _ForwardIterator = Process*; _Allocator = std::allocator<Process>]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:422:8:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_back_aux(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const Process&}; _Tp = Process; _Alloc = std::allocator<Process>]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:923:23:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Process; _Alloc = std::allocator<Process>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Process]'
prog.cpp:15:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Process'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
```

Comment: Совет: [иногда переключение на `clang` даёт чуть более понятные сообщения](http://ideone.com/OtC7Oq).

Comment: Всё равно ошибка ни чуть не стала понятнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вектор абстрактных классов - это жуть. Не делается так.

```
vector<Process*> processes; // <- а вот так делается
```

Соответственно нужно изменить методы `run/addProcess` с учетом указателей.

### Объяснение

`std::vector<T>` всегда выделяет память под определенное количество объектов типа `T`. Очевидно, что для этого ему нужно знать их размер. Даже если бы `Process` был не абстрактным, то при попытке `push_back`'нуть в него наследника, он бы автоматически кастовался к типу `Process` (логично: хотя бы для совпадения размера). 
Вторая проблема в том, что сам класс абстрактный и не может иметь экземпляров. Другое дело, при динамическом создании наследника (`ProcessA`) можно автоматически преобразовать его в указатель на родителя (`Process`). Так как указатели имеют фиксированный размер, то из них замечательно создаётся `std::vector`.
Ну и напоследок: виртуальные функции не имеет смысла использовать с чистыми объектами, только с указателями или ссылками

Comment: Спасибо. Буду знать.